# How to cout a vector from an outside function?

Tags: c++, function, vector, int, return

I am trying to write some code where I take each digit of a number, via an outisde function digitSep(), and place it into a vector, in this case `vector<int> digits;`.

Any idea why I cannot `cout << digits[i]` or `cout << digits.at(i)` in a for loop?

```
std::vector<int> digitSep(int d) {
    
    vector<int> digits;

    int right_digit;              //declare rightmost digit 

    while (d > 0) {
    right_digit = d % 10;         //gives us rightmost digit (i.e. 107,623 would give us '3') 
    d = (d - right_digit) / 10;    //chops out the rightmost digit, giving us a new number
    digits.push_back(right_digit);
    
    }
    return digits;               ///returns us a vector of digits 
}

int main() {
    
    //inputs
    int n; 
    cin >> n; 
    
    vector<int> digitSep(n);   //call the function here with user input n above 
    for (int i = 0; i < digitSep.size(); i++) {
        cout << digits[i] << endl;       ////This is the line that won't work for some reason
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `main`, there's no variable named `digits`. Also, you define a function named `digitSep`, but you never actually call it. The comment says "call the function ...", but the line the comment is on does not in fact call any functions (unless you count the vector's constructor).

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
vector<int> digitSep(n);
```

doesn't call the function called `digitSep`. You need to do:

```
vector<int> digits = digitSep(n);
```

And then in the `for` loop, you have to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < digits.size(); i++) {
    cout << digits[i] << endl;   
}
```

or simply:

```
for (int i : digits) {
    cout << i << endl;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here

1. `vector<int> digitSep(n);`  is a constructor call, initializing vector containing n elements each initialized to zero.
2. Main function knows nothing about variable `vector<int> digits;` since it is in local scope of `std::vector<int> digitSep(int d)` function